# NeoVim make terminal window automatically close when program exits

Tags: neovim

The vim version has a [++close](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-close) option that automatically closes the terminal when the job terminates, but since the NeoVim terminal came first it doesn't have that feature.

I need this because i am trying to run programs directly from vim, but i regularly make
curses applications which the popup window you get from `:!python %` can't handle, so i need the terminal window.

It would also be helpful to only close if exit code is 0, so i can read the error message, or some kind of "press enter to exit, or something to stay".

I am using NeoVim on arch linux if that's relevant.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I wonder if neovim has something functionally like the job api, which has an `exit_cb` handler for when the job ends, which also gives you the exit status.

Comment: You can't run your program in a shell within the terminal window? Then you could do `python <args> && exit` which will exit only on success.